# R separate strings in column with or without delimiter

Tags: r, dplyr, delimiter

I'm trying to split a column with some strings with a delimiter and other strings without a delimiter. Here is my example dataframe:

```
df <-  data.frame(ID = c(1:5), Comment = "A; apple", "banana", "C; cherry", "D; dragonfruit", "elderberry")
```

I want to separate the columns so that it looks like below:

```
ID    ColumnA    ColumnB
1        A        apple
2        NA       banana
3        C        cherry
4        D        dragonfruit
5        NA       elderberry
```

I first tried using `separate` in `dplyr`, then `strsplit`, but this created `NA`s in `ColumnB` instead of `ColumnA`.

```
df2 <- df %>% separate(Comment, into = c("ColumnA", "ColumnB"), sep = ";")
```

How can I tell R that it should just put the string in `ColumnB` if it doesn't find the `;` delimiter?

Comment: If there are only two values to separate, use the `fill = "left"` argument.  `df %>%  separate(Comment, into = c("ColumnA", "ColumnB"), fill = "left")`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!